# How many blocks would 1 km be in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to get the "On a Rail" achievement, but I can't seem to go far enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each block is the equivalent of one meter. Given that there is 1000 meters in 1 kilometers, you would have to build a track that spans 1000 blocks in one direction.

Answer (score 3):

1 km is 1000 minecraft blocks. I tried creating a circular track, like so:

[image: Circular rail]

However this did not work, as the achievement states you must travel 1000 blocks from your starting point. So, the only reasonably viable method to the achievement would be this:

[image: Straight rail]

If you're doing it in creative, it's rather easy - took me around 15 minutes to build the rail, and 2-3 minutes to ride it. If you're doing it in survival, I'd recommend the following tips:

- Find an abandoned mine shaft, and take every single track you can find. This is a lot better than using precious iron for minecart tracks.
- If you crafted all 1000 tracks from scratch, you'd be using **375 iron ingots.**
- 1000 tracks is equivalent to fifteen full stacks, plus a little more.